# Amazon RDS SQL Server Specification

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I am about to launch an internal reporting and analytics SQL Server instance on Amazon RDS and am hoping someone can help me out with the answers to a few questions about instance specifications. Here are the specifications of the instance.

- Intended for internal reporting for a Small / Medium business of 100 - 500 people depending on growth.
- Total DB size should not exceed 10TB over the next 3 years - that's being generous.
- Data input should not exceed 10GB per day during peak business months.
  ETL & Processing will generally be done early morning before staff arrive for work.
- DB will only be used for reporting and analytics - no customer facing or business critical applications, though it will be used for business facing, micro and strategic decision making. SSRS, SSAS, some machine learning but mostly reporting.

Here are my questions - sorry if they seem a bit random.

1. What size RDS instance would you recommend? I have been looking at db.m4.2xLarge (8vCPUs 32GB RAM), but there is also r3, r4 and m3. The price difference is fairly significant - several thousand per year. Will the difference make a difference to my users?
2. The cost difference between Single and Multi AZ is massive. How often does a single AZ go down? If it is < 1hr per month then is there any reason for me to bother with Multi AZ?
3. Will a General Purpose SSD be sufficient? I don't think the throughput will warrant Provisioned IOPS. In the Ts&Cs it say you get "Baseline is 3 IOPS per GiB", so for a 2TB initial instance I would get 6,000 IOPS for free anyway. Am I reading that wrong?
4. On a non cloud instance I would usually separate the Data, Log & tempdb onto different drives. Is this necessary on a cloud instance? If so how would it be done?
5. How often would you take an instance snapshot rather than DB Backup up and log shipping?

I am assuming that SQL Server Standard will be sufficient here. If you think I would need Enterprise please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about Amazon RDS (and most platform-as-a-service databases) is that you don't have to have all the answers at the beginning of your project.

Just start with a relatively small instance size. As you do the project development, you'll be able to see how your queries and your tables perform, and make adjustments to your instance sizes over time.

The cloud is all about flexibility: go with the flow. Now, having said that, you asked:

**Q: What size RDS instance would you recommend?**

Use ec2instances.info for a quick comparison, and start with something small - say, 4 cores, 30GB RAM, like an r3.xlarge. (If you're only doing table design initially, before you do loads, you may even start smaller than that.) No sense in paying by the hour for something that's not getting used.

**Q: The cost difference between Single and Multi AZ is massive. How often does a single AZ go down? If it is < 1hr per month then is there any reason for me to bother with Multi AZ?**

Start by asking your users for their desired [RPO and RTO](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/). Their users (and their wallets) the ones who determine how much high availability and disaster recovery you need. Typically, for internal reporting apps, a single AZ is fine, but the RPO/RTO your users come up with will guide you.

**Q: Will a General Purpose SSD be sufficient?**

It's going to depend on your tables, indexes, and queries. I would start development with general purpose SSD, and then monitor your server's wait stats over time. As user queries start to come in, you can learn performance tuning with wait stats to figure out whether you should tune queries, tune indexes, or throw money at virtual hardware to solve the problem.

**Q: On a non cloud instance I would usually separate the Data, Log & tempdb onto different drives. Is this necessary on a cloud instance?**

You're overthinking it: the point of RDS is that they manage these things for you.

**Q: How often would you take an instance snapshot rather than DB Backup up and log shipping?**

In RDS, you don't do any of those things. Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) is like DBA-as-a-service: they do those things for you.

**Q: I am assuming that SQL Server Standard will be sufficient here. If you think I would need Enterprise please tell me why?**

Start your development with 2016 Standard SP1, which gives you a lot of the table design functionality of Enterprise Edition, but just not the DBA tooling.